# When I type this in my search bar in google chrome /students/{student_name} I want to get this name of the array list

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, arraylist, request

Here is my code, but how do I get the name?

```
public function Class(Request $request) {
    $ClassList = ["Arian Drugzani", "Daniëlle Korterink", "Ilse Elskamp", "Janick Dragt", "Jens Bouma", "Marijn Boeve", "Mark Vos", "Mike Beekman", "Nick Bongers", "Ramon van Lohuizen", "Rutgher van de Vosse", "Sacha Veldhoen", "Sil Bosma", "Sophie Nieuwenhuis", "Thijmen de Lange", "Wessel Hakvoort"];
    echo "<h1 style='font-family: sans-serif;'> Zoek resultaten voor: " . $request -> student . "<h1>";

    foreach ($ClassList as $positie => $student){
        echo "<h2>" . $positie. "   ".$student . "<h2>";
    }

    return view('/students/student', ['ClassList' => $ClassList]);
}
```

Here is the route:

```
Route::get('/students/{student}', 'JensController@Class');
```

Comment: you use `echo` and you return view. You have some strong structure in your site.

Comment: Yea this is an exercise for school we have to do it like this way, but the teacher don't wanna help me out :/

Comment: its laravel project?

Comment: Jep that's right

Comment: can you add code from view as well? and delete echo from function named class, and rename function to be something like getStudent
view is in `resources/views/students/student.blade.php`

Comment: There is nothing in the student.blade.php just the html and body tag

Comment: Add your route also in question. @JensBouma

Comment: This is the route Route::get('/students/{student}', 'JensController@Class');

Comment: `foreach ($ClassList as $positie => $student){
        if($request->student == $student)
              echo "<h2>" . $positie. "   ".$student . "<h2>";
}`

Comment: Then nothing happens

Comment: check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views) site and dont try o just do something, try to make it in the right way, right now you code is totally wrong you should read, watch tutorials or learn from your teacher else you will not succeeded

Answer (score 0):

Try this. you need to directly pass `$student_name` in function `Class($student_name)`.

Also change `/students/student` with your blade view file path like if file name is student then  `return view('students', ['ClassList' => $ClassList]);`

```
public function Class($student_name) {
    $ClassList = ["Arian Drugzani", "Daniëlle Korterink", "Ilse Elskamp", "Janick Dragt", "Jens Bouma", "Marijn Boeve", "Mark Vos", "Mike Beekman", "Nick Bongers", "Ramon van Lohuizen", "Rutgher van de Vosse", "Sacha Veldhoen", "Sil Bosma", "Sophie Nieuwenhuis", "Thijmen de Lange", "Wessel Hakvoort"];
    echo "<h1 style='font-family: sans-serif;'> Zoek resultaten voor: " . $student_name . "<h1>";

    foreach ($ClassList as $positie => $student){
        echo "<h2>" . $positie. "   ".$student . "<h2>";
    }

    return view('/students/student', ['ClassList' => $ClassList]);
}
```

Comment: Yea, but I mean I want to get the name of the search bar so the $student_name out of the array list with the position.

Comment: in balde.view file you need to define `{{ route(students',$student) }}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function Class($student) {
    $classList = ["Arian Drugzani", "Daniëlle Korterink", "Ilse Elskamp", "Janick Dragt", "Jens Bouma", "Marijn Boeve", "Mark Vos", "Mike Beekman", "Nick Bongers", "Ramon van Lohuizen", "Rutgher van de Vosse", "Sacha Veldhoen", "Sil Bosma", "Sophie Nieuwenhuis", "Thijmen de Lange", "Wessel Hakvoort"];

    $studentName = urldecode($student);

    echo "<h1 style='font-family: sans-serif;'> Zoek resultaten voor: {$studentName}<h1>";

    foreach($classList as $key => $name) {
        if ($studentName == $name) {
            echo "<h2>{$key} {$name} <h2>";
        }
    }

    return view("students")->with("classList", $classList);
}
```

Replace students in  `return view("students")` with whatever the name of your view is.

And in your web.php

```
Route::get('/students/{student}', 'JensController@Class');
```